# Why zero is not shown after decrementing in the output?It is timeout program

Tags: javascript, decrement

here is link to my code http://codepen.io/meow414/pen/adLoEY  please have a look.The sec variable is not showing 0 when sec=0,it is performing while sec==0 thing but not showing 0 after decrementing?How to show it.

```
var min = 0;
var sec = 3;
var over;

function xyz() {
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;

    sec--;    //it is getting decremeted upto 0,that's why below while loop is running bu in output zero is not shown for ex 3 after decrementing will show like 3 then 2 then 1 then it will chnage to 9.

    while(sec == 0) {
        sec = 9;
    }
}

$("#start").click(function() {
    over=setInterval(xyz, 1000);
});

$("#pause").click(function() {
    clearInterval(over);
});

$("#reset").click(function() {
    min = 0;
    sec = 5;
    clearInterval(over);
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
});
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question--it is unclear what is happening. Also, change your title so it isn't so long (you needn't post the whole question in the title)

Comment: sorry i was in a hurry let me change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function uses `while` as a condition (instead of `if`).

Also, when you change `sec` from 1 to 0, you immediately set it to 9 with that condition.

Try

```
 function xyz() {
   // Show sec, even if it's 0
   document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec; 
   // Then if(sec===0) set sec to 9 (the HTML will still show 0)
   if (sec === 0) {
     sec = 9;
   }
   // Otherwise, decrement sec
   else {
     sec--;
   }
 }
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxGBbd

Comment: I can't put else there, I am using many if else conditions in the original program and they all need to derement sec.